# ORA-12519 TNS: No appropriate service handler found in JBoss 7.2

Tags: jboss, datasource, jboss7.x, sqlexception, ora-12519

I'm migrating some projects from JBoss 6.4 to JBoss 7.2, these projects needs different datasources to configurate DB connections. I added the datasources to the JBoss server config file (standalone.xml):

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/SCL" pool-name="SCL" enabled="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@someIP:somePort:RCBDDES</connection-url>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>pass</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/Oracle" pool-name="jdbc/dsOracle" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@someIP:somePort:RCBDDES</connection-url>
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>25</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>35</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>pass</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</check-valid-connection-sql>
            <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
            <background-validation>true</background-validation>
            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
        </validation>
        <timeout>
            <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
            <blocking-timeout-millis>6000</blocking-timeout-millis>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
            <query-timeout>60</query-timeout>
            <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
            <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
            <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
            <track-statements>true</track-statements>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/dsSQLServer" pool-name="jdbc/dsSQLServer" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://someIP:somePort;DatabaseName=name</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
        <driver>sqlserver</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>25</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>35</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>pass</password>
        </security>
        <timeout>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
            <track-statements>true</track-statements>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/dsSQLServerHH" pool-name="jdbc/dsSQLServerHH" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://someIP:somePort;DatabaseName=name</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
        <driver>sqlserver</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>25</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>35</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>pass</password>
        </security>
        <timeout>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
            <track-statements>true</track-statements>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="oracle" module="oracle.jdbc">
            <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft">
            <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

The server starts without problems and I can execute store procedures used in the project, but I'm receiving constantly the following warning in the server console [`ORA-12519`] (even without making a request, only starting the server):

```
[#2020-05-21 17:25:12,983 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:/jdbc/Oracle: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1326) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.fillTo(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1138) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar:1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:386)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
    ... 11 more
#]
```

Can someone give me and advice?

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously caused by the fact that the listener was not accepting connections, Could you connect your database through sqlplus? Also, you can navigate through the Jboss admin console/localhost:9990 by default/ and click test connection button to check your configuration. Maybe your database client version and DB version are not compatible. You may have connection leak that means there is no room for your pool size of respective datasource or at the database. And check out this link http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_12519_tns_no_appropriate_service_handler_found.htm